# Catia D.S.L.S. DSLicSrv -admin Dos Utility

Tags: catia

I am currently trying to write a batch file to export from the D.S.L.S. licence manager a list of current users using Catia. We use D.S.L.S. within our company to distribute Catia licences. The licences we use are DP2,MD2 and ST1 licences. The problem arises when I try to pass parameters in the batch file. Essentially I don't know how to do this for this dos utility.  To launch the utility enter DSLicSrv -admin at the dos prompt. The c localhost 4084 connects to D.S.L.S. licence manager. The glu command essentially exports a list of current users to the ListCatiaUsers.txt file in the temp folder on the c:\ drive. The d command disconnect from the D.S.L.S. licence manager. The quit command exits from the utility. The only way I could get this does utility to work properly is entering the parameter at the keyboard. I would however like to automate this process in a batch file.

Any help much appreciated.

```
C:
CD\
CD Program Files\Dassault Systemes\DS License Server\win_b64\bin
DSLicSrv –admin
admin > c localhost 4084
admin > glu >c:\temp\ListCatiaUsers.txt
admin > d
admin > quit
CD\
```

I tried the approach below in a batch file but no success.

```
C:
CD\
CD Program Files\Dassault Systemes\DS License Server\win_b64\bin
DSLicSrv –admin
echo c localhost 4084|admin > 
echo glu >c:\temp\ListCatiaUsers.txt|admin > 
echo d|admin > 
echo quit|admin > 
CD\
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the above question is as follows below. The batch file below launches the DSLicSrv -admin utility and logs on to the D.S.L.S. licence manager in addition to that it also exports a text file ListCatiaUsers.txt to the c:\temp directory. This text file contains a list of all current Catia users accessing a licence from the D.S.L.S. licence manager at a point in time. The batch file also disconnects the user from the D.S.L.S. licence manger and quits the utility. Note in order for this batch file to work it must be run from the server where the D.S.L.S. licence manager is installed.

```
c:
cd\
cd program files\dassault systemes\ds license server\win_b64\code\bin
DSLicSrv -admin -run "c localhost 4084;glu >c:\temp\ListCatiaUsers.txt;d;quit" 
cd\
```